# $L/K$ is unramified extension implies corresponding local extension $L_P/K_p$ is unramified?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field and $L/K$ be finite galois extension.

Let $p$ be a prime ideal of ring of integers of $K$.
Let $P$ be a prime ideal above $p$.
Let's think about corresponding local extension $L_P/K_p$, where $L_P$ and $K_p$ denotes completion of $L$ and $K$ with prime ideal $P$ and $p$.

> My question is, $L/K$ is unramified at $p$ implies $L_P/K_p$ is
> unramified ?

If there is only one prime above $p$, because completion of Dedekind domain keeps ramification degree and inertia degree, we can say corresponding local extension is umramified, but if there are more than 2 primes above $p$, I think we have no way to prove the statement.

But I'm having trouble finding counterexamples. This question asks concrete counterexample and the explanation why that forms counterexample,Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an extension $L/K$ of algebraic number fields (Galois or not), suppose a prime $p$ of $K$ factors as $pO_L=P_1^{e_1}\ldots P_g^{e_g}$. We say that $p$ is unramified in that extension if and only if all exponents $e_i$ are $1$.

From some little theorems in algebraic number theory, each extension $L_{P_i}/K_p$ of completions has ramification degree/index $e_i$.

So if the $L/K$ is ("globally") unramified over $p$, it is locally unramified at all primes lying over $p$.

Or do you mean to ask about something else here?

Comment: Oh, that's it. I knew inertia degree does not change under completion, but didn't know the extension keeps ramification degree, so I was stuck but ramification degree does not change under completion, I understand ! Is  'Little theorem'  「Extension of Dedekind domains keeps ramification degree 」, right ?

Comment: I don't know a name for it... it's entangled with a lot of basic results concerning completions...